# Promise.all for objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Promise.all can turn `[Promise a, Promise b]` into `Promise [a, b]`, which is super useful, but is there also a way to turn `{a: Promise a, b: Promise b}` into `Promise {a, b}`.

The use case is:

I have a function that loads some files from a website and gives back error messages in the case that it failed.
This means, that its signature is `information -> {values: values, messages: messages}`.

But the whole check is async, so it turns out to be `information -> {values: Promise values, messages: promise messages}`

Comment: `Promise.All([information.values, information.messages]).then(() => {//success}).catch((err) => {//error})`, doesn't do the job ?

Comment: Why not change your function to have the signature `information -> Promise {values: values, messages: messages}` right away? Also why does it return both values and messages at the same time, shouldn't it return either?

Comment: @Bergi it's more like it's logging, not really displaying one single error message

Comment: @hgiesel OK, I understand that, but is there any reason why the logging promise would resolve at a different time than the values promise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my super simple solution:

```
export const objectZip = (keys, values) =>
  keys.reduce(
    (others, key, index) => ({
      ...others,
      [key]: values[index],
    }),
    {}
  );

export const objectPromise = async obj =>
  objectZip(Object.keys(obj), await Promise.all(Object.values(obj)));
```

Comment: `export function objectZip(keys, values) { const o = {}; for (const [key, index] of keys) o[key] = values[index]; return o; }` looks much simpler though (and doesn't require experimental syntax)

Comment: @Bergi Is the order of iteration between calls to `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` on the same instance guaranteed to be identical?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, they both use [EnumerableOwnProperties](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerableownproperties) which doesn't guarantee any particular order, but always the same one. But you're right, it would be safer to use `Object.entries()` once and then split it into an array of keys and an array of values.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed `entries` so far, which is why my answer is a bit round-about. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it manually:

```
function objectPromise(obj) {
    return Promise.all(Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
        return Promise.resolve(obj[key]).then(function (val) {
            return {key: key, val: val};
        });
    })).then(function (items) {
        var result = {};
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            result[item.key] = item.val;
        });
        return result;
    });
}
```

usage

```
var testObj = {
    a: Promise.resolve("a"),
    b: Promise.resolve("b"),
    c: "c"
};

objectPromise(testObj).then(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
//> { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }
```

---

Same thing in ES6 syntax, if you prefer that:

```
var objectPromise = obj => Promise.all(
    Object
    .keys(obj)
    .map(key => Promise.resolve(obj[key]).then(val => ({key: key, val: val})))
).then(items => {
    let result = {};
    items.forEach(item => result[item.key] = item.val);
    return result;
});
```

Comment: seems  way more elegant at usage. i cant perceive  return usage with promises.
it makes no sense :)

Answer (score 0):

No as i know but you can prepare a return object and you will know when its ready

```
function multipleAsyncJobs(){
    ret = {};
    var a = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        ret.a = someVal; // set 
        resolve();
    })
    var b = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        ret.b = someVal; // set 
        resolve();
    })
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Promise.all([a,b]).then(function(){
            resolve(ret)
        })
    })
}
```

u can use this func like this so that returns a promise as usual

```
multipleAsyncJobs().then(ret=>{
console.log(ret.a)
})
```

Comment: Your `multipleAsyncJobs()` cannot be called multiple times at once

Answer (score 0):

I would dare to suggest another option (with some further hints):

```js
export async function promiseAllOfObject(obj) {
  const values = await Promise.all(Object.values(obj));
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
    (res, key, index) => (res[key] = values[index], res),
    {}
  );
}
```

Respectively replacing `Promise.all` to `Promise.allSettled` will give you `promiseAllOfObjectSettled()` function.

And, as a small bonus, here is typescript version (replacing to `Promise.allSettled` works the same as above):

```ts
export async function promiseAllOfObject<
  T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>,
>(obj: {
  [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]>;
}): Promise<T> {
  const values = await Promise.all(Object.values(obj));
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, key, index) => {
    res[key] = values[index];
    return res;
  }, {} as Record<string, unknown>) as T;
}
```